# Nested while loop in SQL Server is not showing the expected result

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect records from two different tables so I can display the data in a tabular format in an SSRS tablix.

The code below does not return the expected results.

As is, for each item in `Temp_A` the loop updates everything with the last item in `Temp_C`. Here is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp_A
(
    [ID] INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp_A ([ID], [Name]) 
VALUES (1, 'A'), (2, 'B')

CREATE TABLE #Temp_C
(
    [ID] INT,
    [Name] VARCHAR(255)
)

INSERT INTO #Temp_C ([ID], [Name]) 
VALUES (1, 'C'), (2, 'D')

CREATE TABLE #Temp_Main
(
    [Temp_A_ID] INT,
    [Temp_A_Name] VARCHAR(255),
    [Temp_C_ID] INT,
    [Temp_C_Name] VARCHAR(255),
)

DECLARE @MIN_AID int = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #Temp_A)
DECLARE @MAX_AID int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Temp_A)

DECLARE @MIN_DID int = (SELECT MIN(ID) FROM #Temp_C)
DECLARE @MAX_DID int = (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM #Temp_C)

WHILE @MIN_AID <= @MAX_AID
BEGIN
    WHILE @MIN_DID <= @MAX_DID
    BEGIN       
        INSERT INTO #Temp_Main([Temp_A_ID], [Temp_A_Name])
            SELECT ID, [Name]
            FROM #Temp_A 
            WHERE ID = @MIN_AID

        UPDATE #Temp_Main
        SET [Temp_C_ID] = ID, [Temp_C_Name] = [Name]
        FROM #Temp_C
        WHERE ID = @MIN_DID

        SET @MIN_DID = @MIN_DID + 1     
    END             

    SET @MIN_AID = @MIN_AID + 1 
    SET @MIN_DID = 1
END 

SELECT * FROM #Temp_Main

DROP TABLE #Temp_A
DROP TABLE #Temp_C
DROP TABLE #Temp_Main
```

Incorrect result:

```
Temp_A_ID | Temp_A_Name | Temp_C_ID | Temp_C_Name
----------+-------------+-----------+---------------
1           A             2           D
1           A             2           D
2           B             2           D
2           B             2           D
```

Expected results:

```
Temp_A_ID | Temp_A_Name | Temp_C_ID | Temp_C_Name
----------+-------------+-----------+---------------
1           A             1           C
1           A             2           D
2           B             1           C
2           B             2           D
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

You seem to want a `cross join`:

```
select a.*, c.*
from #Temp_A a cross join
     #Temp_C c
order by a.id, c.id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=092e995c74d45f92740034376cc9c5a0) is a db<>fiddle.

There is no need to write a `WHILE` loop to do this.

You can use `insert` to insert this into `#TempMain`, but I don't se a need to have a temporary table for storing the results of this query.

Comment: I used a temp table because I have to update more columns.I just could figure out this first step. Thank you so much.